# Page Leave Alert In Custom Lightning Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Hi I want to implement a page leave alert in a custom lighting page when the user tries to navigate to a different page without saving the data. It should be similar to the alert we get in standard page.

[image]

What is the best way to implement this. I did not find any lightning event to track the user navigating away from the page.

Comment: I would be surprised if this is possible to implement as aura components have locker service restriction.

Comment: @Raul There's a component for that.

Answer (score 3):

Lightning provides [lightning:unsavedChanges](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation), which is the same functionality as the dialog you've posted in the screenshot. Your custom components must use this component in order to properly block navigation in Lightning when the user attempts to leave a page without saving.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I have a custom page with lightning tab component, which in turn contains custom components. Multiple components can be in edit mode and when the user tries to navigate to a different page I just want to notify the user that there are unsaved data.  Is it possible to achieve this with lighting:unsavedChanges component.

Comment: @vinny should be possible. Each component that can have unsaved data needs to use the component.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox.